# Jenkins CI build timeout for long processes

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, jenkins

We're using Jenkins CI (version 1.454) as execution engine for automated tests (triggered via Ant). One of my tests runs for at least 1-2 days. I couldn't exactly find out, since Jenkins always terminates my test before it finishes. Last time after ~20,5h.

We got the "Build timeout" plugin installed, but the test project in question doesn't have a timeout configured, so it shouldn't interrupt. The tests are running on a slave node. The global Jenkins configuration does not contain any timeout settings.

I've seen two other people having a similar problem, but no answers so far

Stacktrace:

```
INFO: Test-Linux-lts-mc #31 aborted
java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:127)
at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:681)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:158)
at $Proxy37.join(Unknown Source)
at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$ProcImpl.join(Launcher.java:859)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:345)
at hudson.tasks.Ant.perform(Ant.java:217)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:703)
at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.build(Build.java:178)
at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.doRun(Build.java:139)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:473)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1408)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:238)
```

The console log doesn't show any indication to an error or timeout. It just says Build aborted and cleans up the nodes workspace.

Comment: Not that this solves the actual problem, but are you sure tests that take that long to run belong in a continuous integration engine?

Comment: Since we want to run them on a regular basis (every 6h), I think yes. This one test is an exception and takes a bit longer, but since we've build-up the framework for setup and testing our application and in general the test is similar to the other (shorter) ones, it kinda belongs there. For us Jenkins is an execution scheduler.

Comment: This appears to be a log from your master.  Can you share the log from the slave?

Comment: Problem solved: I had a problem in my ant script starting the tests. It didn't start the tests via ant, but with a Java task inside the ant wrapper. Replacing the pure Java call with an ant call solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins itself does not have a timeout. I have 24 hour performance tests and Jenkins does not abort them.

The `java.lang.InterruptedException` makes me think there is a signal from your build process which escapes and hits Jenkins. Are you running ant target using the `Invoke Ant` build step? If you are, you could try to execute a shell build step and in the shell run `ant yourtarget`.

Comment: The basic idea is good. As commented above, I was starting the test with a pure Java, which caused the crash. Calling the test execution with another ant script solved my problem.